# How to leave trail in my sketch without deleting the background in p5js?

Tags: javascript, graphics, trigonometry, p5.js

I would like to leave line trails at each of the corners of the rectangles. I have tried createGraphics to add an extra canvas where I want to leave the trails but it's just doesn't work.

I purposefully rotate the rectangle with cosine. My assignment forbids to use the rotate function.

I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TaluaAD9MKA

The Sketch:

Without createGraphics: https://editor.p5js.org/plaszlo/sketches/W6Bq6zAI3

With createGraphics:  https://editor.p5js.org/plaszlo/sketches/WQhPN5e7F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some problems with your code. You can check [here](https://editor.p5js.org/staccioli/sketches/xrcpKleQK) the solutions I found.

The fixes I needed to do where:

1. To create a Graphic you should use createGraphics (you were using createCanvas instead).
2. As you are translating the shape you draw on the canvas, you should also translate the trails themselves in the trails layer graphic.
3. As you draw the trails, you should also use push() and pop() to save the settings of the graphic at each frame, so the translation doesn't accumulate from one frame to the others.